# Activity monitor stops updating or intermittently updates

Tags: high-sierra, activity-monitor

Since I upgraded to High Sierra, the Activity Monitor has been relatively unusable for me. When I launch it, it updates for a while, but after a while (especially after a time of high CPU load), it plainly stops updating. I can interact with the application, but its displayed information doesn't update anymore.

Switching tabs sometimes seems to trigger one or two updates, but I still can't see current information.

Does anyone know why this happens and more importantly how I can solve it.

Note: I compile a lot of C++, run some graphics intensive programs, sometimes with debugger attached, while having a VM standby in Parallels. I don't think this VM causes the issue as I've observed this behaviour without it being active. I did not see this type of behaviour before upgrading to High Sierra.

Answer (score 1):

I know of 2 options to help you. The first is to open Activity Monitor and click on View menu. The 3rd option on the menu is "Update Frequency". Clicking on "Update Frequency" gives you several options for how fast the screen is updating. Change that to a smaller number and see if that helps.

The second option is to use `top` or `htop` from the command. See how it looks. Activity Monitor is just a user interface for UNIX command top. By typing top on the command line, you are bypassing the user interface part.